# RMySQL incorrectly querying column with type bit

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

We have a database and several columns are of type bit.  When querying them using the RMySQL package, the incorrect results are returned. To reproduce, in a SQL prompt:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
( aId varchar(10) not null,
  aBit bit not null
);

INSERT INTO suppliers (aId, aBit) VALUES ("First", 0);
INSERT INTO suppliers (aId, aBit) VALUES ("Second", 1);
INSERT INTO suppliers (aId, aBit) VALUES ("Third", 0);
INSERT INTO suppliers (aID, aBit) VALUES ("Fourth", 1);
```

I can then run:

```
select * from suppliers
```

and I get:

```
+--------+------+
| aId    | aBit |
+--------+------+
| First  |      |
| Second | ☺    |
| Third  |      |
| Fourth | ☺    |
+--------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec
```

Great, but if I try to query the table in a R command prompt:

```
library(RMySQL)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='password1', dbname='test', host='localhost')
query = dbSendQuery(mydb,"select * from suppliers")
data = fetch(query, n=-1)
summary(data)
```

On my machine this produces:

```
aId                 aBit  
 Length:4           Min.   :0  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:0  
 Mode  :character   Median :0  
                    Mean   :0  
                    3rd Qu.:0  
                    Max.   :0
```

As you can see all the aBit cells in "data" are set to 0.  Anyone know why this is happening and potential work arounds?  Thanks in advance

Comment: This is now fixed in the dev version, but see https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/20 for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a workaround, you can use an [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) clause in MySQL:

```
select aId,IF(aBit,'1','0') as aBit from suppliers
```

This will prevent MySQL from return a bit and should produce a value that R can handle without issue.

Comment: `SELECT aId, aBit + 0 AS aBit FROM suppliers` is a little simpler